# ASP.NET MVC Routing with a single optional parameter e.g. site.com/optionalparameter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've been testing a few alternatives for a site that needs to support e.g.

```
site.com
site.com/Controller/Action/id
site.com/various.aspx
site.com/optionalparameter  <-- these two go to the same controller
site.com/optionalparameter/ <-- these two go to the same controller
```

I actually need to verify if the optional parameter is acceptable, but I can direct it to a controller that will verify it. The other rules seem to work so far but I haven't been able to get the single optional parameter working yet.

The optional parameter in the url can be used with or without a slash "/" (at least without). I've found similar questions but they seem to have "optionalParam/xx/yy" so the rules have more parameters and they seem to work fine, but this is a bit of a special case converting a non-mvc site to use MVC routing.

An example of what I am trying to do, but isn't working.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "optionalParamRoute", 
    "{name}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", name = "" }
);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: optionalParamRoute - i have tested, it definetly works, maybe you have additional routes in in routes config which match to **site.com/optionalparameter** thats why it not work

Comment: Yes you are correct, moving it to the top of the RegisterRoutes catches it. Thank you!

Comment: Please select mark my answer as right.

Comment: You could also use the [ASP.NET Routing Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) to see what route is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move to top your optionalParamRoute parameter:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "optionalParamRoute", 
    "{name}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", name = "" }
);

// other routes
```

Comment: The other rules in my RegisterRoutes were interfering with the single optional parameter, as well as a `folder` in the application with the same name as the "optionalparameter". Note that as long as there is a folder with the same name it ignored the MapRoute despite the rule hitting correctly.

Comment: Set `routes.RouteExistingFiles = true` to prevent this from happening